# Base64 encode single row in an array

Tags: php, android, base64, gson

I'm building an Android app, that is supposed to be able to take a photo, and then store it in a database. I got that part down. However when I try to load it into my app again, that's when it gets tricky.

I have the image stored as a longblob in my DB, and I can see from the json readout in my logcat, that the longblob is being returned as a string. A very long string, that I can not handle. When I try to add to my gson created wrapper class, it just gives me a nullpointer.

Now, I've seen several places that suggest that I base64_encode it in my php file. I've found a way to do this, but only by adding another array in the php file, and I would like to avoid having to handle to different arrays in my java code.

My php thus far looks like this:

```
<?php
function resultToArray($result) {
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;

       foreach($rows as $key=>$value){ /* Creating this extra array is what I'm looking to avoid. */
           $newArrData[$key] =  $spots[$key];
           $newArrData[$key]['Image'] = base64_encode($spots[$key]['Image']);
       }
     }
     return $rows;
}
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "db_to_use");
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$query = ("SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE Email_FK='{$email}'");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$rows = resultToArray($result);
echo json_encode($rows);

$result->free();
?>
```

I'm returning 9 different values, image included. Is there a way to avoid creating the newArrData array, so I only have to handle the one in my code?

My wrapper class in the java code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by KasperG on 22/04/2015.
 */
public class Card implements Serializable {
    private String Email_FK;
    private String BarcodeNumbers;
    private String MemberNumber;
    private String StoreID;
    private String CardID;
    private String HasBarcode;
    private String StoreName;
    private String CustomCard;
    //private Base64 Image;


    public Card() {

    }

    public Card(String barcodeNumbers, String memberNumber, String storeID, String hasBarcode, String cardID, String storeName, String CustomCard) {
        this.StoreID = storeID;
        if (barcodeNumbers.isEmpty()) {
            this.BarcodeNumbers = null;
        } else {
            this.BarcodeNumbers = barcodeNumbers;
        }
        if (memberNumber.isEmpty()) {
            this.MemberNumber = null;
        } else {
            this.MemberNumber = memberNumber;
        }
        this.HasBarcode = hasBarcode;
        this.CardID = cardID;
        this.StoreName = storeName;
        this.CustomCard = CustomCard;
    }
    /*
    public Card(String memberNumber, String storeID) {
        this.memberNumber = memberNumber;
        this.storeID = storeID;
    }
    */

    public String getBarcodeNumbers() {
        return BarcodeNumbers;
    }

    public String getMemberNumber() {
        return MemberNumber;
    }

    public String getHasBarcode() {
        return HasBarcode;
    }

    public String getCardID() {
        return CardID;
    }

    public String getStoreName() {
        return StoreName;
    }

    public int getStoreID() {
        return Integer.parseInt(StoreID);
    }

    public String getCustomStore() { return CustomCard; }

    //public Base64 getImageString() { return Image; }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MemberNumber: " + MemberNumber + "\n" +
                "BarcodeNumbers: " + BarcodeNumbers + "\n" +
                "Store ID: " + StoreID + "\n" +
                "Has Barcode " + HasBarcode + "\n" +
                "Card ID: " + CardID + "\n" +
                "Store Name: " + StoreName + "\n" +
                "Custom Card? " + CustomCard + "\n" +
                "Image String: " /*+ Image*/;
    }
}
```

The "Image" variable is out-commented on purpose, because if I don't do that, it doens't work at all!

And where I use gson to create the class'es from the wrapper;

```
public ArrayList<Card> getCards(MyCardsScreenActivity activity) {
    myCards = activity;

    String email = SaveSharedPreferences.getUserName(activity);
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String link = "http://test.wallyy.com/new_get_card_info.php?email=" + email;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(link));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("Pass3?", data.toString());

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Card[] cards1 = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), Card[].class);
        for(Card card : cards1) {
            cards.add(card);
            Log.d("Card toString;\n", card.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {}

    if (!cards.isEmpty()) {
        myCards.setHasCards(true);
    }
    else {
        myCards.setHasCards(false);
    }
    return cards;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Edit:
As per @CJ Wurtz' suggestion, I changed my php file to this;

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['Image'] = base64_encode($row['Image']);
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

However, this still doesn't work on the Android side. Updated my wrapper class to this;

```
public class Card implements Serializable {
    private String Email_FK;
    private String BarcodeNumbers;
    private String MemberNumber;
    private String StoreID;
    private String CardID;
    private String HasBarcode;
    private String StoreName;
    private String CustomCard;
    private Base64 Image;


    public Card() {

    }
```

But the minute I add the Image variable, the gson doesn't create any instances of the wrapper class.

Reedit: Just realized that I had the wrong http method pasted. The updated one, the `public ArrayList<Card> getCards(MyCardsScreenActivity) {...}` one is the one I am calling to create instances of the wrapper class and adding them to an arraylist.

Comment: What do you mean "The "Image" variable is out-commented on purpose, because if I don't do that, it doens't work at all!"? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Exactly. I doesn't work when the Image variable is not outcommented. However, now my code is not working at all and I don't know why.

Anyways, I am not getting any errors. I can see the JSON output, as I log it, however, I will not create any instances of the wrapper class, if the wrapper class has the Image variable. And I need to get the image back into the system.

Comment: It's not working at all, but it must be doing SOMETHING. **What is that wrong something?**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, [**a specific problem or error**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So, I got it to work! I basically just changed the Base64 Image to a String Image, then did some Base64 decoding in another place in my code. I apologize for the poorly formulated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wrapper class was setup wrong. I was uncertain as how to handle the response from the server, but by making a few changes in my wrapper class, I got it to work.

My wrapper class now looks like this;

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    /**
     * Created by KasperG on 22/04/2015.
     */
    public class Card implements Serializable {
        private String Email_FK;
        private String BarcodeNumbers;
        private String MemberNumber;
        private String StoreID;
        private String CardID;
        private String HasBarcode;
        private String StoreName;
        private String CustomCard;
        private String Image;


        public Card() {

        }

        public Card(String barcodeNumbers, String memberNumber, String storeID, String hasBarcode, String cardID, String storeName, String CustomCard, String Image) {
            this.StoreID = storeID;
            if (barcodeNumbers.isEmpty()) {
                this.BarcodeNumbers = null;
            } else {
                this.BarcodeNumbers = barcodeNumbers;
            }
            if (memberNumber.isEmpty()) {
                this.MemberNumber = null;
            } else {
                this.MemberNumber = memberNumber;
            }
            this.HasBarcode = hasBarcode;
            this.CardID = cardID;
            this.StoreName = storeName;
            this.CustomCard = CustomCard;
            this.Image = Image;
        }

        public String getBarcodeNumbers() {
            return BarcodeNumbers;
        }

        public String getMemberNumber() {
            return MemberNumber;
        }

        public String getHasBarcode() {
            return HasBarcode;
        }

        public String getCardID() {
            return CardID;
        }

        public String getStoreName() {
            return StoreName;
        }

        public int getStoreID() {
            return Integer.parseInt(StoreID);
        }

        public String getCustomStore() { return CustomCard; }

       public String getImageString() { return Image; }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MemberNumber: " + MemberNumber + "\n" +
                    "BarcodeNumbers: " + BarcodeNumbers + "\n" +
                    "Store ID: " + StoreID + "\n" +
                    "Has Barcode " + HasBarcode + "\n" +
                    "Card ID: " + CardID + "\n" +
                    "Store Name: " + StoreName + "\n" +
                    "Custom Card? " + CustomCard + "\n" +
                    "Image String: " + Image;
        }
    }
```

Changing the type of the Image variable to String, made this;

```
public ArrayList<Card> getCards(MyCardsScreenActivity activity) {
        myCards = activity;

        String email = SaveSharedPreferences.getUserName(activity);
        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String link = "http://address.com/new_get_card_info.php?email=" + email;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Pass3?", data.toString());

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Card[] cards1 = gson.fromJson(data.toString(), Card[].class);
            for(Card card : cards1) {
                cards.add(card);
                Log.d("Card toString;\n", card.toString());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {}

        if (!cards.isEmpty()) {
            myCards.setHasCards(true);
        }
        else {
            myCards.setHasCards(false);
        }
        return cards;
    }
```

work. Then I just had to handle that String;

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(card.getImageString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Again, sorry for the poorly formulated question. I will try to keep my questions more to the point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just overwrite the "Image" element with the base64_encoded version?

Ie:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row['Image'] = base64_encode($row['Image']);
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

I'm not sure where that `$spots` array is coming from, so maybe this solution won't work for you, but basically just saying for each row you get back from the database, update that array for the row before you add it to the eventual result array you'll return.

Comment: Sorry, offhand I'm not sure how to get the mapping to work correctly for the base64 type, I'm not familiar with how you are doing that mapping (I've only used Dozer to do the json mapping in java).  You could do a work around of just using a String type, and then create a getter or helper that returns the base64 type and does the conversion within.  I imagine you'll have to decoding on the base64 string anyway to display the image, maybe kill two birds.. Sorry I can't be or more help.

Comment: Thanks man. The few one line in the php file was actually all I needed.